# Solo me deja enviar una vez al servidor - Javascript WebSockets

Tags: javascript, python, flask, websocket

Ando realizando un proyecto en *Python3 + Dart + Flutter + JavaScript + Flask + WebSockets*... Entonces, de JavaScript he logrado hacer todo lo que necesitaba, sin embargo, tengo un error en el envío de datos al servidor creado en Python3 (servidor de tipo WebSockets localhost).

El problema es que para enviar solo me permite una vez, luego me dice que la conexión se ha cerrado. Si recargo la web me deja enviar más datos al servidor WebSockets.

Código:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function sendNow(e){
        socket.send('Hola');
      }
    </script>
 
    <script type="text/javascript">
 
      var socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8765");
      var image= document.getElementById("image");
      image.onclick = sendNow;
 
    </script>
 
  </head>
  <body>
    <img id="image" alt="" src="imagen.png" width="1366" height="768"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Debes mantener la conexión abierta del lado del servidor.** Si estás utilizando un servidor como el del primer ejemplo en la documentación de [python websockets](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html):

```py
import asyncio
import websockets

async def hello(websocket, path):
    name = await websocket.recv()
    print(f"< {name}")

    greeting = f"Hello {name}!"

    await websocket.send(greeting)
    print(f"> {greeting}")

start_server = websockets.serve(hello, "localhost", 8765)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Al establecer la conexión y responder al mensaje la conexión se cerrará. **Para mantener la conexión abierta implementa un *bucle infinito*:**

```py
import asyncio
import websockets

async def hello(websocket, path):

    while True:
        name = await websocket.recv()
        print(f"< {name}")

        greeting = f"Hello {name}!"

        await websocket.send(greeting)
        print(f"> {greeting}")


start_server = websockets.serve(hello, "localhost", 8765)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Pero **una mejor opción** que un *bucle infinito* es un **bucle que se detenga cuando el usuario se desconecte:**

```py
import asyncio
import websockets

async def hello(websocket, path):

    conection_open = True

    while conection_open:

        try:

            name = await websocket.recv()
            print(f"< {name}")

            greeting = f"Hello {name}!"

            await websocket.send(greeting)
            print(f"> {greeting}")

        except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedError:
            conection_open = False


start_server = websockets.serve(hello, "localhost", 8765)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Un saludo!